# Get screen coordinates by specific location and longitude (android)

Tags: android, augmented-reality, latitude-longitude

I have an application of augmented reality in which I have stored information such us metro, gas stations, places of interest, etc. with the corresponding latitude and longitude.

Now, according to the orientation of the device, I would show a marker for each site in the camera view of the device. Similar to Layar and Wikitude.

It takes three days searching without stopping and have not found anyone to explain how to solve this problem.

Comment: This kind of apps are not trivial, so it's unlikely to find a code that does exactly that. So... **what have you tried to do?** sometimes there's no choice by doing things by yourself... of course, if you get stuck with a specific problem in your implementation that IS something you can ask for help.

Comment: There is probably no exact code for what I want to do but maybe someone knows how it should do.

I need to know exactly where on the screen (x and y coordinates) I have to draw each of the sites that I have stored. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b64_16K2e08 0:25 minutes

Comment: Carro, have you solved this problem? I have the EXACT same problem.  So far, I have been able to find the direction to the latitude/longitude and display an arrow (like a compass) pointing in the general direction of the POI, but I cannot figure out how to translate that lat/lon into a screen X coordinate (nevermind the y coordinate for now). I know the distance and the bearing, but I feel like I'm missing an important piece, like a projection formula. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since information on this topic is very sparse, and I recently solved this problem on the iPhone, I thought I would share my method for anyone that can make it work with Android (there's nothing really specific to iPhone in this answer except for the Math functions sin, cos, and fmod, which can be found in java.lang.Math). These are the steps I took:

- Obtain your own lat/lon and your current compass heading (lat1, lon1 and heading). On the iPhone, CLLocation returns these in degrees, but for these calculations they **MUST** be in radians (i.e. multiply by PI/180)
- Obtain lat/lon of Points of Interest (POI) in radians (lat2 and lon2).
- Calculate the distance between lat1/lon1 and lat2/lon2 using formula found here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
- Calculate angle to lat2/lon2 in relation to north.  This is also described in the link above but I had a little bit of trouble getting this to work, here is C code for this:

  `double latDelta = (lat2 - lat1);`
  `double lonDelta = (lon2 - lon1);`
  `double y = sin(lonDelta)  * cos(lat2);`
  `double x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2)* cos(lonDelta);`
  `double angle = atan2(y, x); //not finished here yet`
  `double headingDeg = compass.currentHeading;`
  `double angleDeg = angle * 180/PI;`
  `double heading = headingDeg*PI/180;`
  `angle = fmod(angleDeg + 360, 360) * PI/180; //normalize to 0 to 360 (instead of -180 to 180), then convert back to radians`
  `angleDeg = angle * 180/PI;`
- Using standard trigonometry, I calculate x and y. Remember, these coordinates are in 3D space, so we are not finished here yet because you still have to map them to 2D:

  `x = sin(angle-heading) * distance;`
  `z = cos(angle-heading) * distance; //typically, z faces into the screen, but in our 2D map, it is a y-coordinate, as if you are looking from the bottom down on the world, like Google Maps`
- Finally, using the projection formula, you can calculate screen x ( I didn't do y because it was not necessary for my project, but you would need to get accelerator data and figure out if the device is perpendicular to the ground).  The projection formula is found here (scroll to the very bottom): http://membres.multimania.fr/amycoders/tutorials/3dbasics.html

  `double screenX = (x * 256) / z`

Now you can use this x coordinate to move an image or a marker on your screen. Remember a few points:

- Everything must be in radians
- The angle from you to the POI relative to North is angleBeteweenPoints - currentHeading

(For some reason I can't properly format the code on this computer, so if anyone wants to edit this answer, feel free).

Comment: hey http://membres.multimania.fr/amycoders/tutorials/3dbasics.html is broken. Can you please tell how did u calculate screenY. Also when you said "returns these in degrees, but for these calculations they MUST be in radians (i.e. multiply by 180/PI)" it actually should be PI/180

Comment: what is 256 in your calculation for screenX?

Comment: You were right about the comment about 180/PI, I fixed it, thanks (funny thing is the code was ok). I did not calculate y in my project, but it should be straightforward if you get accelerometer data (the angle to the ground). My guess is it would be y*256/z - it's a shame that link is down but i found a cached copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20121103042635/http://membres.multimania.fr/amycoders/tutorials/3dbasics.html

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the quick reply. So for calculating screen Y you need to obtain the float y = event.values[1] right? and then use screenY = y *256/z  ...Am i right?

Comment: event.values[1] correspond to the value we get from the accelerometer. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: As far as getting y from the phone, it depends on what your framework provides. Take a look here for iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070931/ios-calculating-distance-azimuth-elevation-and-relative-position-augmented , it could be similar for Android.

Comment: Do you mean the azimuth value? I am able to get that from the compass? So then the question is do I really need to access the accelerometer?

Comment: No, the azimuth value is a horizontal measurement of the angle difference between the object and you. What you need is elevation which, in that link above, is obtained from the device "roll". (In reality, this isn't really an *accelerometer* function, it's a gyroscope function, but when mobile devs refer to "accelerometer data" they usually mean a combination of accelerometer data and gyroscope data). Take a look at the variable "y" in that link above