# Augmented reality - 3D to 2D point projection

Tags: 3d, 2d, projection

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314724/get-screen-coordinates-by-specific-location-and-longitude-android) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) it is explained how to get screen coordinates by specific location and longitude, that is 3D to 2D. I want to learn the same with projection matrices. I've found a lot of materials, but still having problems to understand matrices, how they work etc. Can someone explain it in a plain and simple manner in order to get a picture in my head? Because it' is all very, very fuzzy in my head.

Thansk in advance.

Best regards.