# iOS - Calculating distance, azimuth, elevation and relative position (Augmented Reality)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, augmented-reality

I am starting to build an augmented reality app where you can place an image on the screen on your augmented reality camera view and it stays in that position on the Earth, so someone else with their camera view can come by and see it on the augmented reality camera view. For this I know I need to calculate some sort of distance factor along with azimuth and elevation.

So, I have already figured out how to send the object's graphics up to a server and retrieve it back, but how can I place it back on its original position, relative to Earth. I know I need to calculate its:

- Altitude
- Coordinates
- Azimuth
- Elevation
- Distance

But how would I calculate these and account for them/piece them together. I hope you understand what I mean.

To refine your understanding let me give you a short demo of the app:

A man is in his house, he decides to place an image of a painting on one of his walls. He opens up the app which defaults to the augmented reality screen, he presses the plus button and adds an image from his photo library. Behind the scenes, it saves the location and positional data up to a server, someone with the app and its augmented reality screen comes by, it goes up to the server and finds images saved nearby, it then downloads the image and places it up on the wall so the other man can see it with his phone when he moves it by.

What approach should I take to achieve this? Any outline, links, resources, tutorials, thoughts, experience etc. Thanks! This was a generally hard question to write down, I hope you can understand. If not please tell me and I will reword.

Rohan

Comment: It's actually calculating projection based on your current location and target location. You may get some idea here: https://github.com/abm-adnan/Radar/blob/master/Radar/Controllers/RadarViewController.m#L104

Comment: @MCKapur How are you fetching the positional data of the image from and sending it to server? Like I knew the initial position of the image what if the user drags the image to a new position in the AR screen view, now how to identify the new lat/long of the image?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm working on two AR iOS apps which do the following: convert azimuth (compass, horizontal angle) and elevation (gyroscope, vertical angle) to a position in 3D space (e.g. spherical to cartesian).

The frameworks you need are:

- CoreLocation
- CoreMotion

Getting the geolocation (coordinates) is pretty straightforward for latitude, longitude, and altitude. You can easily find this information in several online sources, but this is the main call you need from the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` after you call `startUpdatingLocation`:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    latitude = (float) manager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    longitude = (float) manager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    altitude = (float) manager.location.altitude;
}
```

Getting the azimuth angle is also pretty straightforward, using the same delegate as the location after calling `startUpdatingHeading`:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    azimuth  = (float) manager.heading.magneticHeading;
}
```

Elevation is extracted from the gyroscope, which doesn't have a delegate but is also easy to set up. The call looks something like this (note: this works for my app running in landscape mode, check yours):

```
elevation = fabsf(self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll);
```

Finally, you can convert your orientation coordinates into a 3D point like so:

```
- (GLKVector3)sphericalToCartesian:(float)radius azimuth:(float)theta elevation:(float)phi
{
    // Convert Coordinates: Spherical to Cartesian
    // Spherical: Radial Distance (r), Azimuth (θ), Elevation (φ)
    // Cartesian: x, y, z

    float x = radius * sinf(phi) * sinf(theta);
    float y = radius * cosf(phi);
    float z = radius * sinf(phi) * cosf(theta);
    return GLKVector3Make(x, y, z);
}
```

For this last part be very wary of angle and axis naming conventions as they vary wildly from source to source. In my system, θ is the angle on the horizontal plane, φ is the angle on the vertical plane, x is left-right, y is down-up, and z is back-front.

As for distance, I'm not sure you really need to use it but if you do then just substitute it for "radius".

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, quite a valuable answer. Ill go more in this and get back to you. I would probably need the distance so I can scale down the image when you are further away. BUt what do you mean substitute it for "radius"? Will that work? Also could you if possible point me to a resource that uses this / similar code so I can see it actually this in use?

Comment: I'm using the radius to drive a directional light around a 3D object, so given your new information I think the radius is irrelevant to you. From what I understand, the distance you are seeking will be calculated as the difference between two points on earth, yes? (If so, I can't help you there!) Also, AR is relatively new to apps so you'll struggle to find much useful information, but I implemented this technique for my MSc thesis and a follow-up app currently being reviewed by Apple. Both were developed within the past 6 months and I've struggled to find relevant code examples!

Comment: What do you mean by directional light? I know its not relevant to me, but just asking (it sounds cool)... So I have my 3d point here, how can I get my 3d point and draw an image back on the area/location? I retrieve the coordinates, altitude, azimuth and elevation and then how do I draw it back? Another thing is, the image might be a small image in the centre of the screen. So how can I draw the image back to the position on Earth but ALSO to the position relative to the screen? And another question, will these calculations be VERY accurate? Will it give an accurate location if I draw it back?

Comment: Also, how can I convert the GLKVector3 to an NSData object? Is that possible?

Comment: A directional light is a common 3D CG object that closely emulates direct sunlight - it is infinitely far away and exclusively emits parallel rays. Sounds like you've still got a lot of design ground to cover, so it's hard to give more advice unless I start perusing the fine details of your implementation and ultimate goals. From personal experience, the position relative to the screen is the trickiest and will depend greatly on how you define your scales and distances (e.g. when is the user "close" enough?). Math is math, any inaccuracies will lie with the sensors :)

Comment: To convert GLKVector3 to NSData, NSCoder could be useful.

Comment: GLKVector3 is just an array of 3 floats. It comes from Apple's GLKit framework which is very useful in 3D mathematics. I haven't used NSData before though.

Comment: @RicardoRendonCepeda Thanks, one last question. How can I draw the image back on the screen based on these calculations?

Comment: I would render them as textures using OpenGL ES 2.0. However, I'm sure there is an easier way that's more suitable to your design choices. Graphics programming has quite a steep learning curve for beginners and you probably won't need all the extra firepower offered.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you pull it off. The app sounds exciting!

Comment: Haha thanks, but I still have one last question and everything will be wrapped up. You said to render the textures using OpenGL ES 2.0, but how can we render the textures to be placed at that azimuth, altitude, elevation, coordinates...

Comment: Have a think, you already have all the information you need - it's a case of relative positions and orientations now. It seems like you need to go over your design carefully and start solving the puzzle bit by bit, else I'd be writing the whole app comment by comment!

Comment: @RicardoRendonCepeda If I understood correctly, last method will give a vector which is a device camera vector and coordinate origin is in the centre of device(sort of). y is headed normal to earth. Is that correct?

Comment: @haawa  What will be the value of radius here?

Comment: @RicardoRendonCepeda Where are you using the latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

Gyroscope code update:

```
import CoreMotion
...
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { deviceManager, error in
            guard let dm = deviceManager else { return }
            let roll = dm.attitude.roll
            let pitch = dm.attitude.pitch
            let yaw = dm.attitude.yaw

            print("r: \(roll), p: \(pitch), y: \(yaw)")
        }
```

Comment: what about azimuth?